# Available helpers / classes to parse ranges between two Time values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been attempting to solve an issue that I'm working on & not sure if there are any tools / helpers available which I'm missing to help me come to a solution / point me in the right direction.

I'm trying to read in two Time values, a start & an end. From there I need to create two new variables, one which contains the minutes which are inside a time range, and another with the minutes outside the range.

I've tried multiple approaches but can't seem to follow a correct path or find any useful methods.

```
# Range to check between: (1pm - 7pm)(13 - 19)

@begin_time # Sun, 16 Feb 2020 05:11:33 UTC +00:00
@end_time   # Sun, 16 Feb 2020 19:43:42 UTC +00:00

#inital check to see if there are any values inside the range
@begin_time <= 13 && @end_time <= 17

# create an array containing all of the minutes between the two points, but not sure
# how I can compare these against the two times, as I don't believe you can create a static Time value
# total_range --> ["05:11", "05:12"... etc]
total_range = begin_time.strftime('%H:%M')..end_time.strftime('%H:%M').to_a

# could possibly generate the minutes in between the 1pm & 7pm values like above, compare the
# values - where the ones which exist = inside_values & the ones which don't = outside_values

# this would theoretically give me a basis of what I need, but doesn't look to be possible outside of the console
(@begin_time - CONST_ONE_PM_TIME) / 60
(CONST_SEVEN_PM_TIME - @end_time) / 60
```

If anyone has any ideas or prompts on what I could potentially look into going forward, it would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is off-topic because you're asking us to recommend tools/code that are off-site. Instead, the SO way is that you research, find candidates, pick the one you want to try, work with it a while, and then, after trying and trying, ask a specific question about that particular problem that has you stumped. "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)",
"[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)" will help explain the process.

Comment: Have you read Ruby's [Date](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/index.html), [DateTime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html) and [Time](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Time.html) documentation multiple times? There's lots of good information there. Also, see "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".

Comment: Do `@begin_time` and `@end_time` always fall on the same date? If not, do we assume the beginning of the range has the same date as `@begin_time` and the end of the range is on the same date as `@end_time`?

Comment: Maybe I'm dense but I would really like to see examples of the input and expected output as I still don't get what you're doing.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yep the focus here is on the hours that are both within the same day :)

Comment: @max Sorry, it's most likely my explanation --> so for the input, there would be `@begin_time` & `@end_time`, both are two Time values. The range, `set_range` would be from 1pm - 7pm. The expected output would be `inside_range` = total number of minutes inside the above range, and `outside_range` = total number of minutes outside the above range.

e.g. if the input was start: 13:04, end: 19:06, the output would be `inside_range: 362`, `outside_range: 7`

Comment: @theTinMan I'm actually just noticing the Time comparison `<=>` now. I think I may be able to use that in some shape! One of my main issues was also how to compare that time value with a non Time object (i.e. the preselected 1pm-7pm range)

Comment: When a comment asks for clarification it's best to respond by editing your question, as not all readers read all comments. Questions should be self-contained. When you edit there is no need that you have done so (no "EDIT:..."), for example. The only rule is to not alter the question.

Comment: Is this wrong: `@end_time <= 17` ... should it be this: `@end_time <= 19`?  Also, I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding the question, maybe you could clean it up a little, clarify it?  For example, on first reading I can't tell if your function wants to get two inputs or four.

Answer (score 0):

I will address what is effectively the same problem as given in the question, but is structured differently. It should not be difficult to modify the code below to suit the OP's requirements.

**Data**

Suppose we are given the following data.

```
require 'time'
```

```
SECS_PER_30_MINS = 1800
TIME_FMT = '%H:%M'
```

The time interval begins at `'9:00'` and ends at `'16:59:59'`, covering `16` 30-minute slots. Slot `0` is from `'9:00:00'` to `'9:29:59'`, Slot `1` is from `'9:30:00'` to `'9:59:59'`, and so on.

```
start_time = Time.strptime('9:00', TIME_FMT)
  #=> 2020-02-17 09:00:00 -0800

slots = 16.times.map { |i| (start_time + i*SECS_PER_30_MINS)...
  (start_time + (i+1)*SECS_PER_30_MINS) }
  #=> [2020-02-17 09:00:00 -0800...2020-02-17 09:30:00 -0800,
  #    2020-02-17 09:30:00 -0800...2020-02-17 10:00:00 -0800,
  #    2020-02-17 10:00:00 -0800...2020-02-17 10:30:00 -0800,
  #    ...
  #    2020-02-17 16:30:00 -0800...2020-02-17 17:00:00 -0800]
```

Notice that these are three-dot ranges, so the right endpoint of each range is not included in the range.

Suppose we have five events, with starting and ending times as follows:

```
event_times = [['08:00', '09:45'], ['08:30', '10:15'], ['12:34', '14:15'],
               ['11:30', '14:31'], ['15:30', '16:15']]

event_ranges = event_times.map do |s,e|
  Time.strptime(s, TIME_FMT)..Time.strptime(e, TIME_FMT)
end
  #=> [2020-02-17 08:00:00 -0800..2020-02-17 09:45:00 -0800,
  #    2020-02-17 08:30:00 -0800..2020-02-17 10:15:00 -0800,
  #    2020-02-17 12:34:00 -0800..2020-02-17 14:15:00 -0800,
  #    2020-02-17 11:30:00 -0800..2020-02-17 14:31:00 -0800,
  #    2020-02-17 15:30:00 -0800..2020-02-17 16:15:00 -0800]
```

**Code**

```
def slot_availability(slots, event_ranges)
  event_ranges.each_with_object([true]*slots.size) do |er,slot_avail|
  slots.each_with_index do |s,i|
    slot_avail[i] = false if s.cover?(er.begin) || s.cover?(er.end) ||
      er.cover?(s)
    end 
  end
end
```

**Example**

For the arrays `slots` and `event_ranges` defined earlier we obtain:

```
slot_availability(slots, event_ranges)
  #     9:00-  9:30- 10:00- 10:30- 11:00- 11:30- 12:00- 12:30-
  #=> [false, false, false,  true,  true, false, false, false,       
  #    false, false, false, false,  true, false, false,  true] 
  #    13:00- 13:30- 14:00- 14:30- 15:00- 15:30- 16:00- 16:30-
```

**Explanation**

I defined a 16-element array `slot_avail` where `slot_avail[i]` equals `true` (else `false`) if slot `i` is not covered by any event. These values are all initialized to `true`.

The method then enumerates events, for each considering whether any part of the event falls within each slot `i`. There are three patterns in which an event could intrude on a slot:

```
eeeeeeee
    ssssssss  

    eeeeeeee
ssssssss  

eeeeeeeeeeee
  ssssssss
```

See [Range#cover?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F).

**Alternative to use of `Time` objects.**

The use of `Time` objects actually buys very little here. The following is how `slots` and `event_ranges` might be defined without making use of `Time` objects. Each of these arrays contain ranges whose endpoints are numbers of minutes since the previous midnight. The method `slot_availability` is used unchanged.

We start by constructing a simple helper method.

```
def mins_since_midnight(str)
  str.split(':').map(&:to_i).zip([60, 1]).map { |a,x| a*x }.sum
end

mins_since_midnight('09:30')
  #=> 570
```

```
event_times = [['08:00', '09:45'], ['08:30', '10:15'], ['12:34', '14:15'],
               ['11:30', '14:31'], ['15:30', '16:15']]

event_ranges = event_times.map do |b,e|
  mins_since_midnight(b)..mins_since_midnight(e)
end
  #=> [480..585, 510..615, 754..855, 690..871, 930..975]
```

```
start_time = mins_since_midnight('9:00')
  #=> 540

slots = 16.times.map do |i|
  start_time + 30*i...start_time + 30*(i+1)
end
  #=> [540...570, 570...600, 600...630,..., 990...1020]
```

```
slot_availability(slots, event_ranges)
  #=> [false, false, false, true,  true, false, false, false,
  #    false, false, false, false, true, false, false, true]
```